# Does the mouse cable have an impact?

Tags: mouse

Let's start from the top, I had a mouse and used to work no problems.

After awhile it started to freeze for about 2-10 seconds then let go, so i tried to fix it.

i looked it up and the most famous fix that keeps popping up is updating the driver, but since it's just a USB mouse it doesn't  really help.

So i thought i'll open it see if there's a faulty wire or something like.

when i opened it everything seemed okay.

Up to this point the mouse still works, it just have that freezing problem that happens every so often.

So what i did is, i went in and brought an old mouse that is also has a usb cable, and i just switched cables.

However the cable doesn't seem to be compatible, after plugging it in nothing happens, the little microchip on it start to get hot, Which tells you that there's electricity coming in basically the cable is fine (obviously because it worked on the original mouse)

Anyway i thought i'd just the old cable back, now when i did things got weird.

When i plug the mouse in it works fine and the computer recognizes it, now as soon as i try to scroll using the mouse wheel (which used to work just fine) the mouse acts as if it gets unplugged and it just dies.

After some trail and error i found a way to fix it which is to scroll the mouse wheel to a position where the light on the mouse gets brighter then unplug, plug it back in and never scroll again.

To point something out the old mouse that i stole the cable from had a similar problem, when you scroll the mouse wheel the mouse acts as if it unplugged however you can fix it quickly by scrolling back to the previous position which utterly difficult to do.

So my question is does the mouse cable affect the software on the mouse or what's really happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the wiring wrong when you swapped cables & burned out a component.

The next problem is that in burning out a component in the mouse, you may have also damaged the USB bus components in the computer.

Take it all to a repair shop & tell them what you did.

The root cause was more likely to have been software anyway; but you're well past that diagnosis option.

Comment: That's what i thought happened, But there was only one wire (5 pin molex ) which had about 5 tiny wires attached to it but the order of the colors was different,  `you may have also damaged the USB bus components in the computer.` you means the computer's USB port ? because it still works

Comment: @Zohir: Does the cable have wires twisted into pairs? If it does, did you make sure the data line uses paired wires?

Comment: You cannot rely on colours in proprietary components. You need to take it for service so someone competent can analyse it properly. You also need to stop guessing at how things work; it's cheaper in the long run.